# How to detect HDMI IN connected/disconnected using V4L2 requests?

Tags: v4l2, hdmi

I have a board with HDMI IN, i can capture video using V4L2 commands.
Now i need to detect if any laptop is connected/disconnected to that HDMI IN port using a program?

Which v4l2 commands can do that? i have searched a lot on internet and v4l2 official website https://linuxtv.org/

but no luck.